# Hydroponic Chilli plant deficiency

Tags: plant-health, plant-care, chili, hydroponic, deficiency

I've been experimenting with hydroponics chili but no success. Here are some pics.

[image]

[image: List item]

There is no infection or bugs for sure but seems like deficiency of nutrition. Flowers grow but rot very easily and getting just 2-3 chilies in fruiting stage.

I'm feeding it with custom formula at 1200 tds daily. It is getting proper sunlight and temperature is about 18c to 30c. Growing medium is pure cocopeat.

Could some one point out what this deficiency is.

Also let me know if further information is required.

Comment: Are you feeding it? Chili Focus is the go-to food for these plants.

Comment: Obviously, with a custom formula. Around 1200 tds, plant is in cocopeat. It's is also growing fruits but the issue is with the leaves as I explained through pictures.

Comment: It's not obvious when your question doesn't state it. Please update your question with the additional details.

Comment: Sure, I'll do it. I assumed it as it is obvious that a plant can't fruit if not fed at all. Anyways, I'll do it.